# How do I correctly position a Context Menu when I right click a DataGridView's column header?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to extended DataGridView to add a second ContextMenu which to select what columns are visible in the gird. The new ContextMenu will be displayed on right click of a column's header.

I am having difficulty get the correct horizontal position to show the context menu. How can I correct this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGrid;
    ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip;        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid = new DataGridView();
        Controls.Add(dataGrid);
        dataGrid.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        dataGrid.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(ColumnHeaderMouseClick);
        dataGrid.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>().ToList();

        contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("foo");
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("bar");
    }

    private void ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip.Show(PointToScreen(e.Location));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I was going wrong was that DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs returns the location/x,y of where the mouse clicked **within** the column header. Instead I need to use HitTest in the grid's MouseDown event for a hit on the column headers and then convert the position of the hit from the gird co-ordinates to the screen co-ordinates.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGrid;
    ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip;        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid = new DataGridView();
        Controls.Add(dataGrid);
        dataGrid.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        //dataGrid.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += ColumnHeaderMouseClick;
        dataGrid.MouseDown += MouseDown;
        dataGrid.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>().ToList();

        contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("foo");
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("bar");
    }

    private void ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip.Show(PointToScreen(e.Location));
        }
    }

    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (dataGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
            {
                contextMenuStrip.Show(dataGrid.PointToScreen(e.Location));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 91):

Here is a very simple way to make context menu appear where you right-click it.

Handle the event **ColumnHeaderMouseClick**

```
private void grid_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    contextMenuHeader.Show(Cursor.Position);
}
```

`contextMenuHeader` is a `ContextMenuStrip` that can be defined in the Designer view or at runtime.

Comment: This does not compile. 
Context menu needs a parent. The answer below is correct.

Comment: OMG, you helped me alot. Cursor.Position to the rescue

Comment: Great in ease and elegance. Saved a lot of effort if i try solve it using DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs properties like location. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

To get the coordinate of the mouse cursor you could do this.

```
ContextMenu.Show(this, myDataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
```

Comment: This is correct. The accepted answer does not compile.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried using the Show overload that accepts a control and a position?

For example:

```
contextMenuStrip.Show(dataGrid, e.Location);
```

Edit: Full example

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGrid;
    ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip;        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid = new DataGridView();
        Controls.Add(dataGrid);
        dataGrid.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        dataGrid.MouseDown += MouseDown;
        dataGrid.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>().ToList();

        contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("foo");
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("bar");
    }

    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (dataGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
            {
                contextMenuStrip.Show(dataGrid, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The content menu appears in the top left corner of the screen, as e.location is the mouse position within the column header. I have resolved the issue now but thanks for helping.

Comment: According to your answer to your question e.location is within datagrid, not columnheader, so competent_tech was correct.

Comment: It would appear that I tested competent_tech's answer poorly and he is indeed correct if used within the MouseDown event.

Comment: I'm doing similar thing. Im coding for a context menu which should be displayed on the right click of the mouse button. I tried using the ways as from above but i couldnt get it.


        private void treeviewmain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                Point pt = treeviewmain.PointToScreen(e.Location);
                mycontextmenu.Show(treeviewmain, pt);
            }
        }
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

`e.Location` does not show the popup menu at the correct coordinates, instead just use the `MousePosition` property as follows:

```
ContextMenuStrip.Show(MousePosition)
```

or, explicitely

```
ContextMenuStrip.Show(Control.MousePosition)
```

Answer (score 4):

The position returned is relative to the cell. So we have to add that offset.

```
    private void grdView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var pos = ((DataGridView)sender).GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, 
            e.RowIndex, false).Location;
            pos.X += e.X;
            pos.Y += e.Y;
            contextMenuStrip.Show((DataGridView)sender,pos);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of everyone's answers, this is the only 1 that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Finally this worked for me.

```cs
ContextMenu.Show(myDataGridView, myDataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Show` twice will get you the exact location of the cursor. This answer is for those whom are unable to get the result with all above answers.

```
private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        contextMenuStrip.Show(dataGrid, e.Location));
        contextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly right. You just need to the apply the `PointToScreen` method to the calling control:

```
private void ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        contextMenuStrip.Show(((DataGridView)sender).PointToScreen(e.Location));
    }
}
```

I think this is the most elegant solution, because it uses only the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` arguments and not `Cursor.Position`.