# Now overload for method 'Show'takes 2 argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on code-editor and I make a mouseevent for rightclick specifically this code:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{               
      lbright.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
      lbright.BringToFront();               
}
```

but the problem was everytime I runs it 'overload for method' error appears and pointing the `.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);`

How can I avoid it?

Comment: What type is `lbright`?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You are trying to show a list box at the current mouse position on a right click. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, a hint-list? something like copy, paste, cut, etc.?

Comment: And why don't you use the [correct class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/22c1dx6k.aspx) for that?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i justfound it sir^^ sorry . btw is contextmenu have a complete list already? or i still need to input?

Comment: Read the documentation and check the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/22c1dx6k.aspx) and use the overload of [.Show(Control, Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s00cc2f3.aspx) with an offset you should get your menu showing:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{               
    // build a new ContextMenu with some menu items, let's use copy and paste
    ContextMenu ctxRightClick = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[]
    {
        new MenuItem("Copy"),
        new MenuItem("Paste")
    });

    // as per the documentation, the Point used by .Show is relative to the control you pass in so we calculate an offset from the mouse position
    int xOffset = Cursor.Position.X - myForm.Location.X;
    int yOffset = Cursor.Position.Y - myForm.Location.Y;

    // now show the context menu as a child of myForm at the specified offset
    ctxRightClick.Show(myForm, new Point(xOffset, yOffset));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to display a context menu. Use the class designed for that task: [`ContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/22c1dx6k.aspx).

This class has a `Show` method that lets you position the menu: [`Show(Control, Point)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s00cc2f3.aspx)

Comment: something like this sir: rightcontext.Show(Control, Point); ? i write code in MouseDown event but error Dte.Show(System.Windows.Forms.Control, SYstem.Drawing.Point)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial .

Comment: @Elegiac: As I told you: Read the documentation and check the samples. They clearly show how to use that method.

Comment: sir i try it and it worked! problem was i still get the overload error on show, i try all codes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199019/how-do-i-correctly-position-a-context-menu-when-i-right-click-a-datagridviews-c but still that error exist :( what should i do to delete that error? thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear: the [`Control.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) method has only one overload: one without parameters.

If you want to move the control, set the [`Top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top.aspx) and [`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left.aspx) properties.

Comment: so what should i do with that sir? sorry newbie here . i mean what specific code should i input

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Elegiac there is no "specific code to input". You are programming something, so you have an idea what you want to do. If you explain your idea (in your question, not in comments), perhaps someone can tell you something to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from your question, i think this might help

```
lbright.Top=Cursor.Position.X;
lbright.Left=Cursor.Position.Y;
lbright.Show();
```