# Why in every right click, the context menustrip pop up,how to enable it in a specify position by controlling the right click event?

Tags: c#

Why in every right click, the contextmenustrip pop up,how to enable it in a specify position by controlling the right click event??

Comment: Are you working with winforms? What have you tried till yet, can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the default contextmenustrip and create a new one.
With HitTest on a control you can check if the clicked position is on a element

```
 private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (dataGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
            {
                new ContextMenuStrip().Show(dataGrid, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

See: [How do I correctly position a Context Menu when I right click a DataGridView's column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199019/how-do-i-correctly-position-a-context-menu-when-i-right-click-a-datagridviews-c)